# MATLAB: How to plot a rectangle in 3d space

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following example data:

```
x = [2;4;6;8;10]
y = [10;20;30;40;50]
z = [5;5;5;5;5]
```

I am trying to plot a the 2d x/y surface in 3d space but since z is constant I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  All examples I've tried to follow don't work since the points are colinear.

Thanks

Comment: Is the question about a rectangle or "a the 2d x/y surface"? Your example has five coordinates are are too many for the 4 corners of a rectangle. Does `plot3` not work? What have you tried?

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question.

Comment: try `surf(x, y, ones(5)*5)`

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB there are different was to generate a **'3D rectangle'** also known as **parallelepiped**, [Wolfram definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelepiped.html).

**1.- Defining all solid points**

```
xrange=[0:1:10];
yrange=[0:1:20];
zrange=[0:1:5];
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(xrange,yrange,zrange);
x=x(:);y=y(:);z=z(:);
P=[x y z];

figure(1);
plot3(P(:,1),P(:,2),P(:,3),'.');
axis equal
grid on
```

[image]

```
shp1=alphaShape(P(:,1),P(:,2),P(:,3))

figure(2);
plot(shp1)
axis equal
```

[image]

once an `alphaShape` is built the following `volume` and `surfaceArea` commands can be used :

```
round(volume(shp1))
```

same as

```
(xrange(end)-xrange(1))*(yrange(end)-yrange(1))*(zrange(end)-zrange(1))

surfaceArea(shp1)
```

same as

```
2*xrange(end)*yrange(end)+2*xrange(end)*zrange(end)+2*yrange(end)*zrange(end)
```

**2.- Just using vertices**

```
xrange2=[0 10];
yrange2=[0 20];
zrange2=[0 5];
[x2,y2,z2]=meshgrid(xrange2,yrange2,zrange2);
x2=[x2(:);5];
y2=[y2(:);10];
z2=[z2(:);2.5];
P2=[x2 y2 z2];
Tes=delaunayn(P2);

figure(3)
tetramesh(Tes,P2);
camorbit(40,0);
```

[image]

**3.- With command `patch`**

```
v1=[0 0 0;10 0 0;10 20 0;0 20 0
       0 0 5;10 0 5;10 20 5;0 20 5];
f1=[1 2 3 4 1;5 6 7 8 5];

v2=[0 0 0;0 20 0;0 20 5;0 0 5
      10 0 0;10 20 0;10 20 5;10 0 5];
f2=[1 2 3 4 1;5 6 7 8 5];

v3=[0 0 0;10 0 0;10 0 5;0 0 5
      0 20 0;10 20 0;10 20 5;0 20 5];
f3=[1 2 3 4 1;5 6 7 8 5];

figure(4);
hp1=patch('Faces',f1,'Vertices',v1)
hp1.FaceColor=[0 .5 0];
hp1.FaceAlpha=.5;
hp1.EdgeColor='none';

hp2=patch('Faces',f2,'Vertices',v2)
hp2.FaceColor=[.5 0 0];
hp2.FaceAlpha=.5;
hp2.EdgeColor='none';

hp3=patch('Faces',f3,'Vertices',v3)
hp3.FaceColor=[0 0 .5];
hp3.FaceAlpha=.5;
hp3.EdgeColor='none';

grid on
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');

campos([477 -1122 120])
```

[image]

**4.- Extruding a 2D rectangle**

Command `extrude` requires as import a **geometry file**.

In MATLAB geometry files have these equivalent extensions : `.stl` `.step` and  `.ste`
`.stl` and can be generated with CAD applications like SolidWorks.

Here, given how simple is the case, there's no need for SolidWorks, one can directly generate the required `.stl` file directly.

Following, I generate a **triangulation mesh** and save it to `.stl` to then use command `importGeometry` to build a **2D rectangle** that has the right type to be used as input to command `extrude`.

```
P=[0 0;10 0;10 20;0 20];  % points
T=[1 2 4;2 3 4];               % triangles definition

TR=triangulation(T,P)

figure(5)
triplot(TR)
axis equal
grid on
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');
```

[image]

```
stlwrite(TR,'base1.stl','text')
```

this is the contents of `base1.stl` :

```
solid MATLAB_1
facet normal 0 0 1
  outer loop
   vertex 0 0 0
   vertex 10 0 0
   vertex 0 20 0
  endloop
 endfacet
facet normal 0 -0 1
  outer loop
   vertex 10 0 0
   vertex 10 20 0
   vertex 0 20 0
  endloop
 endfacet
endsolid MATLAB_1
```

now for the extrusion :

```
model = createpde;
b1 = importGeometry(model,'base1.stl');

figure(6)
pdegplot(b1,'FaceLabels','on')

extrude(b1,5)

pdegplot(b1,'FaceLabels','on','FaceAlpha',0.5)

grid on
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
```

[image]